# Handling errors in GLThread.run()

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I just released a new version of my application to the Android market, and my new version has a GLSurfaceView in the activity. Even though I'm not doing anything fancy, I have a large user base, there's a lot of substandard Android phones out there, and I'm invariably getting exceptions in GLThread.run().

What is the recommended way to catch/handle these exceptions without crashing the entire app? Ideally I'd like to be able to catch the error, remove the surface view from the activity and switch off the component that uses OpenGL. I did a bit of searching but mostly found exception reports for Firefox on Android and stuff like that. :)

I'm thinking of just using an uncaught exception handler, switching a shared preferences flag to false, and letting it crash; the next run I won't try to add that GLSurfaceView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up working around the problem with the following code:

```
final UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
        if (thread.getName().startsWith("GLThread")) {
            disableOpenGLStuff();
        }

        // You could wrap this in an else, but I'm not sure how good of an idea it is to leave the application running when a thread has crashed.
        defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, ex);
    });
```